# Jenkins slave using an ssh gateway

Tags: ssh, proxy, jenkins

I have jenkins running on `master.com`, and want to have a slave running on `slave.com`. However, to ssh to the slave I need to go through `gateway.com`. Generally to ssh to this machine from my normal account, I just use ~/.ssh/config to set up a ProxyCommand.

I have replicated this setup in my `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host slave.com
 User felix
 ProxyCommand ssh felix@gateway.com nc %h %p
```

I have public key authentication set up for both the gateway and the slave, such that from the command line I can ssh directly from `jenkins@master.com` to `felix@slave.com` simply by doing `ssh slave.com`.

Unfortunately Jenkins does not seem to respect my .ssh/config setup, and the connection times out (the slave is not reachable directly). The Jenkins slave log file is:

```
java.io.IOException: There was a problem while connecting to slave.com:22
....
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
```

How can I figure out whether or not jenkins is respecting my .ssh/config file? Am I missing a step in configuring the master jenkins account or the .ssh/config file for jenkins?

Comment: I ran into the same issue. Do you have an update @Felix?

Comment: Unfortunately not; my "workaround" was to get a slave machine setup outside of the gateway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of using Jenkin's built in SSH implementation, use the "Launch slave by execution of command on the Master". You can then use the regular ssh command, and take advantage of `.ssh/config` like you're used to. If you click the `?` button next to the option, it should give you all the details you need.

Comment: Thanks! I unfortunately cannot test this since I no longer have access to those machines, but I will mark this as the accepted answer anyways.

Answer (score 4):

The [jenkins-ssh-slaves plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Slaves+plugin) uses the [trilead SSH2 implementation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/trilead-ssh2) written in Java.

~/.ssh/config is only read by [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com/), and won't affect how Jenkins connects to your slaves.